# Rename part of filenames in sub-folders python

Tags: python, file-rename

I have to rename images in main directory with contains sub-folders, script with I using right now do some work but not exactly what I need: I can't find a way to do it properly, now i have it:

```
maindir #my example origin
├── Sub1
│   ├── example01.jpg
│   ├── example02.jpg
│   └── example03.jpg
└── Sub2
    ├── example01.jpg
    ├── example02.jpg
    └── example03.jpg
```

My script do that:

```
maindir
├── Sub1
│   ├── Sub1_example01.jpg
│   ├── Sub1_example02.jpg
│   └── Sub1_example03.jpg
└── Sub2
    ├── Sub2_example01.jpg
    ├── Sub2_example02.jpg
    └── Sub2_example03.jpg
```

And I would like to get it :replace a letters in my filenames by my sub-folder name and keep the origin numbers of my jpg:

```
maindir
├── Sub1
│   ├── Sub1_01.jpg
│   ├── Sub1_02.jpg
│   └── Sub1_03.jpg
└── Sub2
    ├── Sub2_01.jpg
    ├── Sub2_02.jpg
    └── Sub2_03.jpg
```

there is my code 4 witch I using:

```
from os import walk, path, rename
parent = ("F:\\PS\\maindir")
for dirpath, _, files in walk(parent):
    for f in files:
        rename(path.join(dirpath, f), path.join(dirpath, path.split(dirpath)[-1] + '_' + f))
```

what I have to change overhere to get my result???

Comment: do you simply want to remove the string `example` from your filenames? If not, do you know the structure of your filenames? Is the number always at the end? Is it always two digits long? => split at the dot and take the last two chars. If not this might be something for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of that line:

```
rename(path.join(dirpath, f), path.join(dirpath, path.split(dirpath)[-1] + '_' + f))
```

generate a new name using `str.replace`:

```
newf = f.replace("example",os.path.basename(dirpath)+"_")
```

then

```
rename(path.join(dirpath, f), path.join(dirpath,newf))
```

of course if you don't know the extension or the "prefix" of the input file, and only want to keep the number & extension, there's a way:

```
import re
number = (re.findall("\d+",f) or ['000'])[0]
```

this extracts the number from the name, and if not found, issues `000`.

Then rebuild `newf` with the folder name, the extracted number & the original extension:

```
newf = "{}_{}.{}".format(os.path.basename(dirpath),number,os.path.splitext(f)[1])
```

Comment: Merci Jean :-) it works , but did we can use some more options and split the name of origin ex: ABC00039.jpg  << for me over here we have - str+int.jpg , and do this automatically without modifying each time "ABC" when we gonna use our code ??

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I have a thousands of sub-folders and someones of them have a various beginning like sub1- abc00068.jpg ... ; sub2 aaa00055.jpg   etc ... I will have to modify my script each time : did python can read it and change by himself ex: newf = f.replace( str , os.path.basename(dirpath)+"_") ; did python have a options read a letters in filename automatically ?? Like before iv tried to ask You did he can split this name aaa(str-string)00068(int-integer).jpg ???

Comment: ca fonctione  , ennormement merci J-F je suis rester bloquee depuis 9h du mat :-)

Comment: faut pas!! you can accept the answer if it works for you.